# how to center align in LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

> mForm.addComponent(new Label("some text"));

I want to center align my text on the screen.

how can I go about it ? I am using LWUIT 1.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use BorderLayout for this.

```
Form mForm = new Form();    
mForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());    
mForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Label("some text"));
```

For more info see this [example](http://jimmod.com/blog/2010/04/basic-lwuit-tutorial-with-eclipse-pulsar/1).